# Angular4 and data-* attributes with injected variable in nested Component

Tags: angular, typescript, custom-data-attribute

Inside the nested Component of Angular4 have the following piece of code:

```
<a data-activator="classroom-panel-activator"
           data-toggle="collapse"
           data-parent="#accordion-{{ day.date }}"
           href="#info-panel-{{ schedule.referenceId }}"
           >
            Click me
</a>
```

The problem is with `data-parent` and its value of `{{ day.date }}` because when I ran the code in the browser, Angular throws the following:

```
Can't bind to 'parent' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("       <a data-activator="classroom-panel-activator"

       data-toggle="collapse"

       [ERROR ->]data-parent="#accordion-{{ day.date }}"

       href="#info-panel-{{ schedule.referenceId }}"
```

The problem really occurrs when the variable is injected into a `data-*` attribute. If I remove `{{ day.date }}` from it, then it works. Also, if I leave the `{{ day.date }}` and e.g. change the name from `data-parent` to `data-nothing` then error still occurrs (so it's not kind of name conflict with any keyword `parent`).

Of course `{{ day.date }}` object exists and works. It's just does not work in the scenario I have described.

So what is the problem then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use attribute binding

```
<a data-activator="classroom-panel-activator"
           data-toggle="collapse"
           [attr.data-parent]="'#accordion-' + day.date"
           href="#info-panel-{{ schedule.referenceId }}"
           >
            Click me
</a>
```